# mysql date compare not working

Tags: mysql

I have read through threads and search other forum but no luck.

I have two tables, AYEAR and SCHEDULE  as shown here

**AYEAR**

```
ay    Block Block_start_date    Block_end_date  
1213    4    2012-07-09         2013-05-13
1314    4    2013-07-01         2014-05-09
1415    4   2014-06-23          2015-05-08
1516    4   2015-07-06          2016-05-09
1617    4   2016-04-11          2017-05-01
```

**SCHEDULE**

```
scheduleid    sched_start_date   sched_end_date

59576370      2016-04-11        2016-05-06
...
...
...
```

My scheduled event is between 2016-04-11 and 2016-05-06. I want to know which ayear this timeframe falls into.

I am running the following query

```
Select ay, scheduleid, sched_start_date, sched_end_date

from schedule, ayear  o

where scheduleid = 59576370

and block = 4

and sched_start_date >= (select max(block_start_date)
                                   from ayear i
                                   where i.block=  o.block
                                   and sched_start_date >= i.block_start_date 
                                   and sched_end_date <= i.block_end_date 
                                   )

and sched_end_date <=  (select max(block_end_date)
                                   from ayear i
                                   where i.block=  o.block
                                   and sched_start_date >= i.block_start_date 
                                   and sched_end_date <= i.block_end_date 
                                   )
```

It gives me this:

```
ay    sched     sched_start_date sched_end_date block_start_date  block_end_dt

1213  59576370  2016-04-11       2016-05-06     2012-07-09        2013-05-13      
1314  59576370  2016-04-11       2016-05-06     2013-07-01        2014-05-09      
1415  59576370  2016-04-11       2016-05-06     2014-06-23        2015-05-08      
1516  59576370  2016-04-11       2016-05-06     2015-07-06        2016-05-09      
1617  59576370  2016-04-11       2016-05-06     2016-04-11        2017-05-01
```

When I expect to get just the last row.

All date fields in both tables are defined as dates.

I guess my question is, how do I identify overlapping time ranges?

Comment: My scheduled event is between 4/11/16 and 5/6/16. I want to know which ayear this timeframe falls into.

Comment: You are right, but as is why it doesn't filter out where block_start_date and block_end_date fall outside of of sched_start_date and sched_end_date.

Comment: ok. so what is wrong. I am trying to pull all rows from ayear where sched_start_date and sched_end_date falls between block_start_date and block_end_date granted it will give me both 1516 and 1617. why the comparison sched_start_date >= (select max(.... and sched_end_date <= (select (max not having any effect

Comment: solving issue with overlapping time ranges.

Comment: I cant see why you need to use subselects.  I would try to redo it using explicit joins.  If no one else has done it by the time I am at a proper PC, I will do it.

Comment: thanks. basically I am trying to get 1617 row because its timeframe is closed to schedule row. What I am puzzled is why the comparisons against select max() is not filtering out 1213, 1314, 1415, and 1516.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
CREATE TABLE ayear
(ay    INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,Block INT NOT NULL
,Block_start_date    DATE NOT NULL
,Block_end_date   DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO ayear VALUES
(1213    ,4    ,'2012-07-09','2013-05-13'),
(1314    ,4    ,'2013-07-01','2014-05-09'),
(1415    ,4   ,'2014-06-23','2015-05-08'),
(1516    ,4   ,'2015-07-06','2016-05-09'),
(1617    ,4   ,'2016-04-11','2017-05-01');
```

The standard pattern for overlapping time ranges is as follows:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ayear 
 WHERE '2016-05-06' > block_start_date 
   AND '2016-04-11' < block_end_date;
+------+-------+------------------+----------------+
| ay   | Block | Block_start_date | Block_end_date |
+------+-------+------------------+----------------+
| 1516 |     4 | 2015-07-06       | 2016-05-09     |
| 1617 |     4 | 2016-04-11       | 2017-05-01     |
+------+-------+------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: so you duplicated ayear table. how does it give me ay for scheduled event from schedule table that is beteen 4/11/16 and 5/6/16

Comment: For clarity, I've omitted one tiny part of the problem.